# ActiveMQ : When durable subscribers was removed, how can I know?

Tags: activemq-classic

everyone.

activemq.xml

```
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="localhost" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}" persistent="true" schedulePeriodForDestinationPurge="60000" 
offlineDurableSubscriberTimeout="30000" offlineDurableSubscriberTaskSchedule="10000">
</broker>
```

After 30 seconds, offline durable subscribers was removed. 
I know what happened to durable subscribers was removed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have configured your broker this way you already know that an offline subscription will get removed after 30 seconds.  If you want to double check that it's working then you'd need to use the JMX features of ActiveMQ to examine the statistics for inactive durable subscribers to see if the count has decreased.  Since your offline window is so short though you might miss the state change for a subscriber that has gone from online to offline though.